# Simulator hangs con execute browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("navigator.userAgent"

Tags: codenameone

On simulator App hangs on execute browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("navigator.userAgent")

```
        BrowserComponent browserComponent = new BrowserComponent();
        String userAgent = (String) browserComponent.executeAndReturnString("navigator.userAgent");
        String userAgent = "";
        if (userAgent == null) {
            userAgent = "";
        }
```

On console logs:

```
Using:
JCEF Version = 83.4.0.260
CEF Version = 83.4.0
Chromium Version = 83.0.4103.106
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path C:\Users\Kandy\.codenameone\cef\lib\win64
Added scheme search://
Added scheme client://
Added scheme cn1stream://

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53523/devtools/browser/2da17f15-4c86-45d2-98d2-c853b71d3d7a
AppHandler.stateHasChanged: NEW
AppHandler.stateHasChanged: INITIALIZING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this API wasn't deprecated its usage is strongly discouraged in the JavaDocs in favor of [this](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html#execute-java.lang.String-com.codename1.util.SuccessCallback-).

Try:

```
bc.execute("navigator.userAgent", userAgent -> {
   // ... 
});
```

Notice that user-agent is something you submit/set in the browser component so you can determine it.

Comment: Thanks Shai, then I will change all calls to that function.